# Insert bulk data django using raw query

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to enter about 1 millions records to `PostgreSql` since I create table dynamically I don't have any models associated with it so I cant perform `bulk_insert` of django
How is there any method of inserting data in a efficient manner.

I am trying using single insert statement but this is very time consuming and too slow

Comment: What did you tried so far? Any code example?

Comment: actually i have to dump data from salesforce to postgresql where table are selected by the enduser. I have created the table dynamically but now the problem is to insert the data as salesforce can have any number of data thus want to have a efficient method of insertion

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not about django. You better carry the data(not necesarry but could be good) to the server that you want to insert and create a simple python program or sth. else to insert the data.

**Avoid to insert a data at this size by using an http server.**

Comment: then how could i do this ? any suggestion if i am workign outside the http server

Comment: How do you plan to execute  django code if you are working outside the http server?

Comment: i will make start a demon to do so , Is multi threading a good option to do? if yes can u suggest a dummy thread to insert database

Comment: Why multithreading? Just carry the data file to the server then execute an insert script which reads data from this.

Comment: no since due to the python synchronous behavior further processing will also be delayed

Comment: can you give an example step by step about what did you done? Because i did this many times and i didnt have any problems yet.